# Npm 2.x errors on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, express, npm

I have installed NodeJs 4.2.1 and Npm 2.14.7 successfully on Windows 10 x64, but when at the time of gathering dependencies on my new and clean system I'm having several errors. This is what I have done so far:

I have cloned many examples from take: github https://github.com/developit/express-es6-rest-api to name one, when I run `npm install` on it everything works fine, but when I run `npm start` it raises errors for missing packages for instance: babel-core/register, utf8, requests, etc. It seems that npm is not installing the 2nd dependency level way down. How can I fix this?, as I said before I've tried with several tutorials and even with something mine and everything is the same. I need a hand, noob on NodeJS here.

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of npm? I would have expected the older 2.x to still work with node4, but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Npm 2.14.7 comes with Node 4.2.1 instalation, to which version should I upgrade npm and how?

Comment: well, if that's what comes with 4, it should work, but npm 3 has been released. I would have expected the newer version of npm to come with node 4.